# How to Upload Image as Binary

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, postman

I want to upload image as binary, as in Postman we do below

[image]

Here is my code

```
var url = myURLString
url = url.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!

guard let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.4) else {
        return
    }

request.httpBody = imageData
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON { (response) in
        if let JSON = response.result.value as? NSDictionary {
            print(JSON)
        } else {
            let message = response.result.error != nil ? response.result.error!.localizedDescription : "Unable to communicate."
            print(message)
        }
 }
```

**It seems that request is not attaching image file, returning following error message**

> "Response could not be serialized, input data was nil or zero length."

Comment: Why not just use `Alamofire.upload(…)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [alamofire.error Code=-6006 "JSON could not be serialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35374798/alamofire-error-code-6006-json-could-not-be-serialized)

Comment: try `responseString` instead of `responseJSON` and check what error are you getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am retrieving image from gallery and taking the name of the image by using below code:
you can use the below function.

```
func createMultipart(image: UIImage, callback: Bool -> Void){
    // use SwiftyJSON to convert a dictionary to JSON
    var parameterJSON = JSON([
        "id_user": "test"
    ])
    // JSON stringify
    let parameterString = parameterJSON.rawString(encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, options: nil)
    let jsonParameterData = parameterString!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
    // convert image to binary
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.7)
    // upload is part of AlamoFire
    upload(
        .POST,
        URLString: "use your url here",
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            // fileData: puts it in "files"
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(fileData: jsonParameterData!, name: "goesIntoFile", fileName: "json.txt", mimeType: "application/json")
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(fileData: imageData, name: "file", fileName: "ios.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
            // data: puts it in "form"
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: jsonParameterData!, name: "goesIntoForm")
        },
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { request, response, data, error in
                    let json = JSON(data!)
                    println("json:: \(json)")
                    callback(true)
                }
            case .Failure(let encodingError):
                callback(false)
            }
        }
    )
}

let fotoImage = UIImage(named: "foto")
    createMultipart(fotoImage!, callback: { success in
    if success { }
})
```

Answer (score 6):

For swift 3, Alamofire 4
below code will work fine

```
var url = myURLString
url = url.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!
guard let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.4) else {
    return
}

Alamofire.upload(imageData, to: URL(string: url)!, method: .post, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in
    if let JSON = response.result.value as? NSDictionary {
        print(JSON)
    } else {
        let message = response.result.error != nil ? response.result.error!.localizedDescription : "Unable to communicate."
        print(message)
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I do this without Alamofire? Im trying to avoid libraries.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4 and 5**

```
var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL)
urlRequest.httpMethod = "PUT" // POST
urlRequest.setValue("image/jpeg", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
var data = image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: CGFloat(0.5))!
URLSession.shared.uploadTask(with: urlRequest, from: data, completionHandler: { responseData, response, error in
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print(response)
                guard let responseCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode, responseCode == 200  else {
                     if let error = error {
                            print(error)
                      }
                      return
                  }
                          // do your work
              }
}).resume()
```