# Alamofire status code not returned in fail part

Tags: swift, alamofire

I wanna catch some status responses in my failure part of my Alamofire request.

The following code:

```
let URL = "https://api.foo.bar"
Alamofire.request(URL, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<UserResponse>) in
    switch response.result {
    case .success:
        // Yea, it worked.
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)        
    }
    if let httpStatusCode = response.response?.statusCode {
        switch(httpStatusCode) {
        case 418:
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Whoops", message: "I't s a Teapot.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            break
        default:
            print("DEFAULT...")
            break
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Returns for some reason a 500 error, but that's not from the API, but from the code itself, but where is it causing it? I can't figure out how to get the `Status code` responses correctly.

Comment: Have you tried error.errorCode

Comment: you can try this answer :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/47952330/6822622

Comment: @Sulabh "Value of type 'Error' has no member 'statusCode'" nor it has member of 'errorCode'

Comment: Try `error._code` which gives you an [NSError Code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1448136-nserror_codes?language=objc). That occurs when you get no connectivity for example...

Answer (score 0):

You can access status code from response like this :

```
switch response.result {
    case .success(let jsonResult):
        // Case result OK
        print(jsonResult)
    case .failure(let error):
        // Case result Fail error
        if let resp = response.response, resp.statusCode == 401 {
            print("401 statusCode")
        }
}
```