# JSON could not be serialized because of error: The data couldn't be read because it isn't in the correct format

Tags: heroku, vapor

I get error from Vapor 1.5 server deployed to heroku. Swift version installed on heroku Swift 3.1 
JSON could not be serialized because of error: The data couldn't be read because it isn't in the correct format. If I call the server locally, http://0.0.0.0:8080/my/route it is not throwing any error. 
How can I fix this?

```
===========Error===========
Error Code: 4
Error Messsage: JSON could not be serialized because of error:
The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.
Server Error: <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Application Error</title>
        <style media="screen">
          html,body,iframe {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
          }
          html,body {
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
          }
          iframe {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border: 0;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <iframe src="//www.herokucdn.com/error-pages/application-error.html"></iframe>
      </body>
    </html>
Alamofire.AFError.responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))
===========================
```

Server logs:

```
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 93.2M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v13
remote:        https://secure-garden-28988.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote:  !   Warning: You are running on a deprecated stack.
remote:  !   Please upgrade to the latest stack by following the instructions on:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-to-the-latest-stack
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/secure-garden-28988.git
   c44026d..144abef  master -> master
MacBook-Pro:StripePayment bogdanbarbulescu$ heroku logs
2018-05-30T12:03:01.197383+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `App --env=production --workdir=./ --config:servers.default.port=12878`
2018-05-30T12:03:03.094008+00:00 app[web.1]: Production mode enabled, disabling informational logs.
2018-05-30T12:03:03.116578+00:00 app[web.1]: No command supplied, defaulting to serve...
2018-05-30T12:03:03.116707+00:00 app[web.1]: No preparations.
2018-05-30T12:03:03.117882+00:00 app[web.1]: Server 'default' starting at 0.0.0.0:12878
2018-05-30T12:03:04.870729+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-05-30T12:03:07.989892+00:00 app[web.1]: [deprecated] Mozilla certificates have been deprecated and will be removed in future releases. Using 'defaults' instead.
2018-05-30T12:03:07.989934+00:00 app[web.1]: oauthJson line 76 is JSON(node: Node.Node.object(["token_type": Node.Node.string("Bearer"), "access_token": Node.Node.string("ya29.c.ElvLBagSETr9DiPFjitMs4XtijYEdFR1OT4jDQx4WpwKkXX1ghZZQ3fMoaK7_07MlMOh8STSFeP4Xr4MpSeXg9_Sjk1xjBC19sLEWFoUhPMMyYKNem4oTOL-qXK_"), "expires_in": Node.Node.number(3600)]))
2018-05-30T12:03:07.989936+00:00 app[web.1]: [deprecated] Mozilla certificates have been deprecated and will be removed in future releases. Using 'defaults' instead.

2018-05-30T12:03:08.147558+00:00 app[web.1]: [deprecated] Mozilla certificates have been deprecated and will be removed in future releases. Using 'defaults' instead.
2018-05-30T12:03:08.887563+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/cancelbooking/bycleaner" host=secure-garden-28988.herokuapp.com request_id=c4acdc48-ac25-42ed-9092-97bbc8a05b6c fwd="90.219.212.108" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=1266ms status=200 bytes=155 protocol=https
2018-05-30T12:39:40.718231+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2018-05-30T12:39:40.718872+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2018-05-30T12:39:42.031561+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2018-05-30T12:39:42.052902+00:00 app[web.1]: response data  is  on  line  135 Optional(Vapor.Content) and response.json is on  line  135 Optional(JSON.JSON(node: Node.Node.object(["LaundryWash": Node.Node.string("false"), "CancelledBy": Node.Node.object(["1527631309": Node.Node.object(["TimeStampDateAndTime": Node.Node.string("1527694200"), "ChangesMadeBy": Node.Node.string("Cleaner"), "usersUID": Node.Node.string("YL6jLbKq04XF2V0AX9PapH2jv8n2"), "CancelledByCleaner": Node.Node.string("6XkGK4amQ3dmp5DcIEWLWCAChzm1"), "ReasonDebtToCleaner": Node.Node.string("Booking cancelled by cleaner 17 hours, 28 minutes, 12 seconds before booking start time"), "DateAndTime": Node.Node.string("Wed, 30 May 2018 16:30"), "BookingStateTimeStamp": Node.Node.string("1527631309"), "CleanerUID": Node.Node.string("6XkGK4amQ3dmp5DcIEWLWCAChzm1"), "Claimed": Node.Node.string("false"), "TimeStampBookingCancelledByCleaner": Node.Node.string("1527631309"), "AmountDebtToCleaner": Node.Node.string("0"), "BookingNumber": Node.Node.string("236191463"), "CostToCancelByCleaner": Node.Node.string("15"), "FeeReasonChargedToCleaner": Node.Node.string("Booking cancelled by cleaner 17 hours, 28 minutes, 12 seconds before booking start time"), "BookingState": Node.Node.string("Active"), "FeeAmountChargedToCleaner": Node.Node.string("15")]), "1527629794": Node.Node.object(["TimeStampDateAndTime": Node.Node.string("1527694200"), "ChangesMadeBy": Node.Node.string("Cleaner"), "usersUID": Node.Node.string("YL6jLbKq04XF2V0AX9PapH2jv8n2"), "CancelledByCleaner": Node.Node.string("6XkGK4amQ3dmp5DcIEWLWCAChzm1"), "ReasonDebtToCleaner": Node.Node.string("Booking cancelled by cleaner 17 hours, 53 minutes, 28 seconds before booking start time"), "DateAndTime": Node.Node.string("Wed, 30 May 2018 16:30"), "BookingStateTimeStamp": Node.Node.string("1527629794"), "CleanerUID": Node.Node.string("6XkGK4amQ3dmp5DcIEWLWCAChzm1"), "Claimed": Node.Node.string("false"), "TimeStampBookingCancelledByCleaner": Node.Node.string("1527629794"), "AmountDebtToCleaner": Node.Node.string("0"), "BookingNumber": Node.Node.string("236191463"), "CostToCancelByCleaner": Node.Node.string("15"), "FeeReasonChargedToCleaner": Node.Node.string("Booking cancelled by cleaner 17 hours, 53 minutes, 28 seconds before booking start time"), "BookingState": Node.Node.string("Active"), "FeeAmountChargedToCleaner": Node.Node.string("15")]), "1527631550": Node.Node.object(["TimeStampDateAndTime": Node.Node.string("1527694200"), "ChangesMadeBy": Node.Node.string("Cleaner"), "usersUID": Node.Node.string("YL6jLbKq04XF2V0AX9PapH2jv8n2"), "CancelledByCleaner": Node.Node.string("6XkGK4amQ3dmp5DcIEWLWCAChzm1"), "ReasonDebtToCleaner": Node.Node.string("Booking cancelled by cleaner 17 hours, 24 minutes, 11 seconds before booking start time"), "DateAndTime": Node.Node.string("Wed, 30 May 2018 16:30"), "BookingStateTimeStamp": Node.Node.string("1527631550"), "CleanerUID": Node.Node.string("6XkGK4amQ3dmp5DcIEWLWCAChzm1"), "Claimed": Node.Node.string("false"), "TimeStampBookingCancelledByCleaner": Node.Node.string("1527631550"), "AmountDebtToCleaner": Node.Node.string("0"), "BookingNumber": Node.Node.string("236191463"), "CostToCancelByCleaner": Node.Node.string("15"), "FeeReasonChargedToCleaner": Node.Node.string("Booking cancelled by cleaner 17 hours, 24 minutes, 11 seconds before booking start time"), "BookingState": Node.Node.string("Active"), "FeeAmountChargedToCleaner": Node.Node.string("15")]), "1527533036": Node.Node.object(["TimeStampDateAndTime": Node.Node.string("1527694200"), "ChangesMadeBy": Node.Node.string("Cleaner"), "usersUID": Node.Node.string("YL6jLbKq04XF2V0AX9PapH2jv8n2"), "CancelledByCleaner": Node.Node.string("6XkGK4amQ3dmp5DcIEWLWCAChzm1"), "ReasonDebtToCleaner": Node.Node.string("Booking cancelled by cleaner 44 hours, 46 minutes, 6 seconds before booking start time"), "DateAndTime": Node.Node.string("Wed, 30 May 2018 16:30"), "BookingStateTimeStamp": Node.Node.string("1527533036"), "CleanerUID": Node.Node.string("6XkGK4amQ3dmp5DcIEWLWCAChzm1"), "Claimed": Node.Node.string("false"), "TimeStampBookingCancelledByCleaner": Node.Node.string("1527533036"), "AmountDebtToCleaner": Node.Node.string("0"), "BookingNumber": Node.Node.string("236191463"), "CostToCancelByCleaner": Node.Node.string("10"), "FeeReasonChargedToCleaner": Node.Node.string("Booking cancelled by cleaner 44 hours, 46 minutes, 6 seconds before booking start time"), "BookingState": Node.Node.string("Active"), "FeeAmountChargedToCleaner": Node.Node.string("10")]), "1527339097": Node.Node.object(["TimeStampDateAndTime": Node.Node.string("1527694200"), "ChangesMadeBy": Node.Node.string("Cleaner"), "usersUID": Node.Node.string("YL6jLbKq04XF2V0AX9PapH2jv8n2"), "CancelledByCleaner": Node.Node.string("6XkGK4amQ3dmp5DcIEWLWCAChzm1"), "ReasonDebtToCleaner": Node.Node.string("Booking cancelled by cleaner 98 hours, 38 minutes, 30 seconds before booking start time"), "DateAndTime": Node.Node.string("Wed, 30 May 2018 16:30"), "BookingStateTimeStamp": Node.Node.string("1527339097"), "CleanerUID": Node.Node.string("6XkGK4amQ3dmp5DcIEWLWCAChzm1"), "Claimed": Node.Node.string("false"), "TimeStampBookingCancelledByCleaner": Node.Node.string("1527339097"), "AmountDebtToCleaner": Node.Node.string("0"), "BookingNumber": Node.Node.string("236191463"), "CostToCancelByCleaner": Node.Node.string("0"), "FeeReasonChargedToCleaner": Node.Node.string("Booking cancelled by cleaner 98 hours, 38 minutes, 30 seconds before booking start time"), "BookingState": Node.Node.string("Active"), "FeeAmountChargedToCleaner": Node.Node.string("0")]), "1527539792": Node.Node.object(["TimeStampDateAndTime": Node.Node.string("1527694200"), "ChangesMadeBy": Node.Node.string("Cleaner"), "usersUID": Node.Node.string("YL6jLbKq04XF2V0AX9PapH2jv8n2"), "CancelledByCleaner": Node.Node.string("6XkGK4amQ3dmp5DcIEWLWCAChzm1"), "ReasonDebtToCleaner": Node.Node.string("Booking cancelled by cleaner 42 hours, 53 minutes, 29 seconds before booking start time"), "DateAndTime": Node.Node.string("Wed, 30 May 2018 16:30"), "BookingStateTimeStamp": Node.Node.string("1527539792"), "CleanerUID": Node.Node.string("6XkGK4amQ3dmp5DcIEWLWCAChzm1"), "Claimed": Node.Node.string("false"), "TimeStampBookingCancelledByCleaner": Node.Node.string("1527539792"), "AmountDebtToCleaner": Node.Node.string("0"), "BookingNumber": Node.Node.string("236191463"), "CostToCancelByCleaner": Node.Node.string("10"), "FeeReasonChargedToCleaner": Node.Node.string("Booking cancelled by cleaner 42 hours, 53 minutes, 29 seconds before booking start time"), "BookingState": Node.Node.string("Active"), "FeeAmountChargedToCleaner": Node.Node.string("10")])]), "ClaimedBy": Node.Node.object(["1527339080": Node.Node.object(["ProfitForBooking": Node.Node.string("11.184"), "StripeCustomerID": Node.Node.string("cus_CvbxFJcNVbPT6q"), "AmountPaidToCleanerWithoutSuppliesForBooking": Node.Node.string("32.0"), "ChangesMadeBy": Node.Node.string("Cleaner"), "RateNumberCleaner": Node.Node.string("1"), "AmountPaidToCleanerForBooking": Node.Node.string("32.0"), "RatePriceCleaner": Node.Node.string("8"), "usersUID": Node.Node.string("YL6jLbKq04XF2V0AX9PapH2jv8n2"), "CleanerUID": Node.Node.string("6XkGK4amQ3dmp5DcIEWLWCAChzm1"), "Claimed": Node.Node.string("true"), "TimeStampBookingClaimed": Node.Node.string("1527339080")]), "1527630525": Node.Node.object(["ProfitForBooking": Node.Node.string("11.184"), "StripeCustomerID": Node.Node.string("cus_CvbxFJcNVbPT6q"), "AmountPaidToCleanerWithoutSuppliesForBooking": Node.Node.string("32.0"), "ChangesMadeBy": Node.Node.string("Cleaner"), "RateNumberCleaner": Node.Node.string("1"), "AmountPaidToCleanerForBooking": Node.Node.string("32.0"), "RatePriceCleaner": Node.Node.string("8"), "usersUID": Node.Node.string("YL6jLbKq04XF2V0AX9PapH2jv8n2"), "CleanerUID": Node.Node.string("6XkGK4amQ3dmp5DcIEWLWCAChzm1"), "Claimed": Node.Node.string("true"), "TimeStampBookingClaimed": Node.Node.string("1527630525")]), "1527631321": Node.Node.object(["ProfitForBooking": Node.Node.string("11.184"), "StripeCustomerID": Node.Node.string("cus_CvbxFJcNVbPT6q"), "AmountPaidToCleanerWithoutSuppliesForBooking": Node.Node.string("32.0"), "ChangesMadeBy": Node.Node.string("Cleaner"), "RateNumberCleaner": Node.Node.string("1"), "AmountPaidToCleanerForBooking": Node.Node.string("32.0"), "RatePriceCleaner": Node.Node.string("8"), "usersUID": Node.Node.string("YL6jLbKq04XF2V0AX9PapH2jv8n2"), "CleanerUID": Node.Node.string("6XkGK4amQ3dmp5DcIEWLWCAChzm1"), "Claimed": Node.Node.string("true"), "TimeStampBookingClaimed": Node.Node.string("1527631321")]), "1527631560": Node.Node.object(["ProfitForBooking": Node.Node.string("11.184"), "StripeCustomerID": Node.Node.string("cus_CvbxFJcNVbPT6q"), "AmountPaidToCleanerWithoutSuppliesForBooking": Node.Node.string("32.0"), "ChangesMadeBy": Node.Node.string("Cleaner"), "RateNumberCleaner": Node.Node.string("1"), "AmountPaidToCleanerForBooking": Node.Node.string("32.0"), "RatePriceCleaner": Node.Node.string("8"), "usersUID": Node.Node.string("YL6jLbKq04XF2V0AX9PapH2jv8n2"), "CleanerUID": Node.Node.string("6XkGK4amQ3dmp5DcIEWLWCAChzm1"), "Claimed": Node.Node.string("true"), "TimeStampBookingClaimed": Node.Node.string("1527631560")]), "1527539705": Node.Node.object(["ProfitForBooking": Node.Node.string("11.184"), "StripeCustomerID": Node.Node.string("cus_CvbxFJcNVbPT6q"), "AmountPaidToCleanerWithoutSuppliesForBooking": Node.Node.string("32.0"), "ChangesMadeBy": Node.Node.string("Cleaner"), "RateNumberCleaner": Node.Node.string("1"), "AmountPaidToCleanerForBooking": Node.Node.string("32.0"), "RatePriceCleaner": Node.Node.string("8"), "usersUID": Node.Node.string("YL6jLbKq04XF2V0AX9PapH2jv8n2"), "CleanerUID": Node.Node.string("6XkGK4amQ3dmp5DcIEWLWCAChzm1"), "Claimed": Node.Node.string("true"), "TimeStampBookingClaimed": Node.Node.string("1527539705")]), "1527629774": Node.Node.object(["ProfitForBooking": Node.Node.string("11.184"), "StripeCustomerID": Node.Node.string("cus_CvbxFJcNVbPT6q"), "AmountPaidToCleanerWithoutSuppliesForBooking": Node.Node.strin
2018-05-30T12:39:42.052902+00:00 app[web.1]: g("32.0"), "ChangesMadeBy": Node.Node.string("Cleaner"), "RateNumberCleaner": Node.Node.string("1"), "AmountPaidToCleanerForBooking": Node.Node.string("32.0"), "RatePriceCleaner": Node.Node.string("8"), "usersUID": Node.Node.string("YL6jLbKq04XF2V0AX9PapH2jv8n2"), "CleanerUID": Node.Node.string("6XkGK4amQ3dmp5DcIEWLWCAChzm1"), "Claimed": Node.Node.string("true"), "TimeStampBookingClaimed": Node.Node.string("1527629774")]), "1527339197": Node.Node.object(["ProfitForBooking": Node.Node.string("11.184"), "StripeCustomerID": Node.Node.string("cus_CvbxFJcNVbPT6q"), "AmountPaidToCleanerWithoutSuppliesForBooking": Node.Node.string("32.0"), "ChangesMadeBy": Node.Node.string("Cleaner"), "RateNumberCleaner": Node.Node.string("1"), "AmountPaidToCleanerForBooking": Node.Node.string("32.0"), "RatePriceCleaner": Node.Node.string("8"), "usersUID": Node.Node.string("YL6jLbKq04XF2V0AX9PapH2jv8n2"), "CleanerUID": Node.Node.string("6XkGK4amQ3dmp5DcIEWLWCAChzm1"), "Claimed": Node.Node.string("true"), "TimeStampBookingClaimed": Node.Node.string("1527339197")])]), "usersUID": Node.Node.string("YL6jLbKq04XF2V0AX9PapH2jv8n2"), "ReasonDebtToCleaner": Node.Node.string("Booking cancelled by cleaner 17 hours, 24 minutes, 11 seconds before booking start time"), "CleanerUID": Node.Node.string("6XkGK4amQ3dmp5DcIEWLWCAChzm1"), "InsideFridge": Node.Node.string("false"), "BookingNumber": Node.Node.string("236191463"), "ProfitForBooking": Node.Node.string("11.184"), "SuppliesAmount": Node.Node.string("0"), "FeeReasonChargedToCleaner": Node.Node.string("Booking cancelled by cleaner 17 hours, 24 minutes, 11 seconds before booking start time"), "RatePriceCleaner": Node.Node.string("8"), "FeeAmountChargedToCleaner": Node.Node.string("15"), "StripeCustomerID": Node.Node.string("cus_CvbxFJcNVbPT6q"), "SelectedBedRow": Node.Node.string("2"), "PhoneNumber": Node.Node.string("07476254556"), "RateNumberCleaner": Node.Node.string("1"), "BookingCompleted": Node.Node.string("false"), "BookingStateTimeStamp": Node.Node.string("1527631550"), "PaymentID": Node.Node.string("ch_1CW1rILCZ34Ur7XGg2wBQa05"), "RatePriceClient": Node.Node.string("11"), "EmailAddress": Node.Node.string("daria@gmail.com"), "TimeStampBookingSavedInDB": Node.Node.string("1527339012"), "BookingState": Node.Node.string("Active"), "FlatNumber": Node.Node.string("12"), "TimeStampDateAndTime": Node.Node.string("1527694200"), "AmountPaidToCleanerWithoutSuppliesForBooking": Node.Node.string("32.0"), "BookingAmount": Node.Node.string("44"), "RateNumberClient": Node.Node.string("1"), "BookingStatusClient": Node.Node.string("true"), "FullName": Node.Node.string("Daniel Orchard"), "Claimed": Node.Node.string("true"), "SuppliesName": Node.Node.string("I have cleaning supplies"), "FirebaseUserID": Node.Node.string("YL6jLbKq04XF2V0AX9PapH2jv8n2"), "Locality": Node.Node.string("Barking"), "SelectedBathRow": Node.Node.string("3"),   "NumberOfHours": Node.Node.string("4.0"), "ChangesMadeBy": Node.Node.string("Cleaner"), "AmountPaidToCleanerForBooking": Node.Node.string("32.0"), "CancelledByCleaner": Node.Node.string("6XkGK4amQ3dmp5DcIEWLWCAChzm1"), "InsideCabinets": Node.Node.string("false"), "AmountDebtToCleaner": Node.Node.string("0"), "TimeStampBookingCancelledByCleaner": Node.Node.string("1527631550"), "InteriorWindows": Node.Node.string("false"), "BookingStatusAdmin": Node.Node.string("false"), "CostToCancelByCleaner": Node.Node.string("15"), "InsideOven": Node.Node.string("false"), "FrequencyName": Node.Node.string("Once"), "TimeStampBookingClaimed": Node.Node.string("1527631560")])))
2018-05-30T12:39:42.052916+00:00 app[web.1]: [deprecated] Mozilla certificates have been deprecated and will be removed in future releases. Using 'defaults' instead.
2018-05-30T12:39:42.052918+00:00 app[web.1]: [deprecated] Mozilla certificates have been deprecated and will be removed in future releases. Using 'defaults' instead.
2018-05-30T12:39:42.052920+00:00 app[web.1]: [deprecated] Mozilla certificates have been deprecated and will be removed in future releases. Using 'defaults' instead.
2018-05-30T12:39:42.194492+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 15
2018-05-31T15:09:12.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user bibscy@gmail.com
2018-05-31T15:14:39.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build logs
2018-05-31T15:23:04.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user bibscy@gmail.com
2018-05-31T15:28:54.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build logs
2018-05-31T16:31:07.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user bibscy@gmail.com
2018-05-31T16:38:29.385841+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2018-05-31T16:38:29.008353+00:00 app[api]: Deploy c44026db by user bibscy@gmail.com
2018-05-31T16:38:29.008353+00:00 app[api]: Release v12 created by user bibscy@gmail.com
2018-05-31T16:38:29.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-05-31T16:38:34.176865+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `App --env=production --workdir=./ --config:servers.default.port=44193`
2018-05-31T16:38:36.463541+00:00 app[web.1]: Production mode enabled, disabling informational logs.
2018-05-31T16:38:36.472842+00:00 app[web.1]: ***** Error in `App': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00000000020e6560 *****
2018-05-31T16:38:36.533050+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 134
2018-05-31T16:38:36.613151+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-05-31T16:38:36.615245+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-05-31T16:38:41.089753+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `App --env=production --workdir=./ --config:servers.default.port=43368`
2018-05-31T16:38:42.986794+00:00 app[web.1]: Production mode enabled, disabling informational logs.
2018-05-31T16:38:42.996321+00:00 app[web.1]: *** Error in `App': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x000000000294b550 ***
2018-05-31T16:38:43.114123+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-05-31T16:38:43.049786+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 134
2018-05-31T16:42:04.373616+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=POST path="/retrieve/card" host=secure-garden-28988.herokuapp.com request_id=d9a2ba08-84f3-4351-bafa-917c1e058caa fwd="90.219.212.108" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-05-31T16:44:37.339103+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=POST path="/update/feedback" host=secure-garden-28988.herokuapp.com request_id=3312744c-792e-4063-8a63-1d21a10a38fd fwd="90.219.212.108" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-05-31T16:49:48.491755+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=POST path="/charge/stripe" host=secure-garden-28988.herokuapp.com request_id=cd3d611a-569b-467c-a1f6-a63bf07de658 fwd="90.219.212.108" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-05-31T16:51:13.147039+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=POST path="/charge/stripe" host=secure-garden-28988.herokuapp.com request_id=f2ee6735-0306-4009-b8d0-d98c89efe95d fwd="90.219.212.108" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-05-31T16:53:35.866344+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=POST path="/charge/stripe" host=secure-garden-28988.herokuapp.com request_id=a4d632db-ca6b-4160-908e-18cf06932b80 fwd="90.219.212.108" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-05-31T17:03:50.853957+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-05-31T17:03:55.862276+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `App --env=production --workdir=./ --config:servers.default.port=7299`
2018-05-31T17:03:58.278454+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 134
2018-05-31T17:03:58.299536+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-05-31T17:03:58.073702+00:00 app[web.1]: Production mode enabled, disabling informational logs.
2018-05-31T17:03:58.084443+00:00 app[web.1]: *** Error in `App': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000001869580 ***
2018-05-31T17:04:03.405673+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=POST path="/retrieve/card" host=secure-garden-28988.herokuapp.com request_id=b6d7e95e-6f1a-4836-8bef-369469a0fb25 fwd="90.219.212.108" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-05-31T17:04:41.220017+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=POST path="/retrieve/card" host=secure-garden-28988.herokuapp.com request_id=9be1b43a-c20b-48e2-ae82-19065b7d4c74 fwd="90.219.212.108" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-05-31T17:21:36.889814+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=POST path="/claim/booking" host=secure-garden-28988.herokuapp.com request_id=8cd175e0-f102-47d4-ab4e-0bf5adc1aada fwd="213.205.251.116" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-05-31T17:21:56.892310+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=POST path="/claim/booking" host=secure-garden-28988.herokuapp.com request_id=8ed67298-7192-4737-8c3d-bc7887a77f8a fwd="213.205.251.116" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-05-31T17:25:04.070396+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=POST path="/retrieve/card" host=secure-garden-28988.herokuapp.com request_id=9d84a993-f47f-4d14-b2ae-2d7416a99211 fwd="90.219.212.108" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-05-31T17:26:38.234967+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=POST path="/retrieve/card" host=secure-garden-28988.herokuapp.com request_id=82f9c4e8-8905-4f7a-aaf7-7a3cf079f345 fwd="90.219.212.108" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-05-31T17:31:11.556858+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=POST path="/charge/stripe" host=secure-garden-28988.herokuapp.com request_id=0085c6f9-56a4-4b1a-aa76-d45c4f2f54d4 fwd="90.219.212.108" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-05-31T17:33:08.792953+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=POST path="/charge/stripe" host=secure-garden-28988.herokuapp.com request_id=7aaeda34-e0ff-4948-b9fd-b76f5a992ed7 fwd="90.219.212.108" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-05-31T18:24:43.737202+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-05-31T18:24:47.597999+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `App --env=production --workdir=./ --config:servers.default.port=52841`
2018-05-31T18:24:48.702319+00:00 app[web.1]: Production mode enabled, disabling informational logs.
2018-05-31T18:24:48.709006+00:00 app[web.1]: *** Error in `App': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000002194570 ***
2018-05-31T18:24:48.754172+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 134
2018-05-31T18:24:48.772888+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-05-31T19:02:16.101019+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=POST path="/charge/stripe" host=secure-garden-28988.herokuapp.com request_id=deb8aef0-ab45-432f-8b75-b8cc88dc41e9 fwd="90.219.212.108" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-05-31T19:08:16.831884+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=secure-garden-28988.herokuapp.com request_id=460b8d95-a87a-401c-96ba-ed0ebeffe290 fwd="90.219.212.108" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-05-31T19:08:17.151541+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=secure-garden-28988.herokuapp.com request_id=1560fcee-cf87-4c7f-b421-81341a0c115e fwd="90.219.212.108" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-05-31T19:59:04.998941+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=secure-garden-28988.herokuapp.com request_id=85fe73b9-edf8-4dd9-bd31-b8ee48b99853 fwd="90.219.212.108" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-05-31T19:59:05.308604+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=secure-garden-28988.herokuapp.com request_id=c7cd24b0-bbd1-4f24-8c8c-bf6955bf5b43 fwd="90.219.212.108" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-05-31T20:07:32.846560+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-05-31T20:07:37.609077+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `App --env=production --workdir=./ --config:servers.default.port=29169`
2018-05-31T20:07:39.647815+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 134
2018-05-31T20:07:39.665835+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-05-31T20:07:39.570953+00:00 app[web.1]: Production mode enabled, disabling informational logs.
2018-05-31T20:07:39.583404+00:00 app[web.1]: *** Error in `App': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000001907560 ***
2018-05-31T20:15:15.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user bibscy@gmail.com
2018-05-31T20:23:07.560223+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-05-31T20:23:07.109323+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 144abef6 by user bibscy@gmail.com
2018-05-31T20:23:07.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-05-31T20:23:07.109323+00:00 app[api]: Release v13 created by user bibscy@gmail.com
2018-05-31T20:23:11.823947+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `App --env=production --workdir=./ --config:servers.default.port=39733`
2018-05-31T20:23:14.142014+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-05-31T20:23:14.144759+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-05-31T20:23:14.064287+00:00 app[web.1]: Production mode enabled, disabling informational logs.
2018-05-31T20:23:14.071214+00:00 app[web.1]: *** Error in `App': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00000000012bb570 ***
2018-05-31T20:23:14.123366+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 134
2018-05-31T20:23:18.372532+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `App --env=production --workdir=./ --config:servers.default.port=9281`
2018-05-31T20:23:19.856366+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 134
2018-05-31T20:23:19.803630+00:00 app[web.1]: Production mode enabled, disabling informational logs.
2018-05-31T20:23:19.810069+00:00 app[web.1]: *** Error in `App': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000001e4c590 ***
2018-05-31T20:23:19.874068+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-05-31T20:54:48.666238+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-05-31T20:54:57.676303+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `App --env=production --workdir=./ --config:servers.default.port=23839`
2018-05-31T20:54:59.225378+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 134
2018-05-31T20:54:59.164261+00:00 app[web.1]: Production mode enabled, disabling informational logs.
2018-05-31T20:54:59.171129+00:00 app[web.1]: *** Error in `App': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000001a73590 ***
2018-05-31T20:54:59.300220+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
MacBook-Pro:StripePayment bogdanbarbulescu$
```

Comment: Hey Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47952330/5918849

Comment: Yea but in my case the request is not hitting server. In my post service call while making request there is some error in parameter what I am sending but I am not able to reproduce it or my client , but during review the error is coming every-time so my app is getting rejected. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54674453/json-could-not-be-serialized-because-of-error