# JSON could not be serialized because of error:

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am using Alamofire 4.0, While making network call I am getting below error during the app review so that my app is getting rejected. But for me and my client it's working fine we are never getting below error

> JSON could not be serialized because of error:
>   The data couldnâ€™t be read because it isnâ€™t in the correct format.

We also checked that the service call is not hitting the server(so not getting any help from their side), Please find the code snippet

```
manager.request(requestURL, method: .post, parameters: param as? Parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.methodDependent, headers: nil).responseJSON { (responseJson) in

})
```

By putting various types of parameters like special character, nil etc.. we did not able to reproduce the error from our side. But during app review we are getting this error. Please help me!!!

Parameter:
[image]

Comment: Well this happened to me also ,for us it was a backend issue, mainly a notice error type, get your backend checked for this api,

Comment: Yes We checked the log in backend but the request is not hitting the server at all. Where other request is getting hit.

Comment: are you using  almofire ?

Comment: the respsone what you are receiving has special characters. when alamofire try to serialize this error is getting thrown. so your backend team has to send proper json

Comment: This might be the culprit `parameters: param as? Parameters`. `param` should be of type [String:Any] . It should look like `var param = [String:Any]()` and then `manager.request(requestURL, method: .post, parameters: param `. No need to cast as Parameters

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar issue.  Turned out, it was my PHP script receiving the data and sending back erroneous serialized JSON data.  There was an "echo" statement that might have corrupted the serialized data.  Check your server-side code, not for error but for an echo statement or other output that should be commented out.

Answer (score 1):

First try to print in the log if you get any response like this:

```
 Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameter).responseJSON { (response) in

        //For Network Error
        guard response.result.error == nil else {
            print(response.result.error!)
            return
        }

        if let value = response.result.value {
            let json = JSON(value)
            print("myJSON are: \(json)"
        }
    }
```

If this does have any error than tell the server team to check. Also check the app transport security in the **plist** .

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts, But the request is not hitting the server at all. The parsing error is coming from Alamofire Framework!

Answer (score 1):

Struggling with this same error for quite a while, and it did turn out to be  a problem on the server side. Use something like Postman to simulate an API call and see what your server responds with.

Comment: You can also print the server response, even in case of error, with `String(data: response.data!, encoding: .utf8)`. I've seen plenty of times on SO when in some cases, server send back HTML, bad JSON, etc. No need to Postman.

Answer (score 0):

```
      var params = [String:Any]()

        params["stripeToken"] = self.stripeToken
        params["currency"] = "gbp"

  Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: ["Content-Type":"application/json"]).responseJSON { (response) in

 switch response.result {

            case .success:

     print("it's success")


            case .failure(let error):


                print("\n\n===========Error===========")
                print("Error Code: \(error._code)")
                print("Error Messsage: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                if let data = response.data, let str = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8){
                    print("Server Error: " + str)
                }
                debugPrint(error as Any)
                print("===========================\n\n")



            }// end of switch
       } //end of Alamofire
```

Comment: Hi, I am trying out your solution!! hopefully it will work for me.

Comment: Hi @bibscy I modified all my API calls and uploaded new build but still did not get any result. It's rejected again with the same error.

Comment: We logged the requestParameter in firebase and the request parameter  is  "requestParameter": ["device_token": "cBXIAfxpEpk:APA91bH8AZYHqMniP5oGNuHT7czD-wHm_ioE-th1_LkN3_w5w_KUa5grT6Ff73D8j9Kn-xONeK4ytT8ZSfVssG9mf4KwJzhY7WdoSxUHxLKNxyGMI0g9ieHjUF25Pi3KwFXDIQmawmow", "time_zone": "America/Los_Angeles", "device_type": "ios", "username": "demo", "password": "**********", "location": "37.452728,-121.940140"]

Comment: We checked in REST API which is working fine.. ! Couldn't understand why it's not working during review.